# type 'string | null' in not assignable to my enum

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-resolver

there in my ProductGender enum -

```
enum ProductGender {
    Men,
    Women,
}
```

my getProducts service -

```
  public getProducts(
    gender: ProductGender,
    category: ProductCategory
  ): Observable<IProductInterface[]> {
    return this.httpProductService.getProducts(gender, category).pipe(
      catchError((errorResponse: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        let errorMessage: string;

        switch (errorResponse.status) {
          case 400:
            errorMessage = 'Getting products failed';
            break;
          default:
            errorMessage = 'An error occurred';
        }

        return throwError(errorMessage);
      }),
      map((response: IGetProductsResponse) => response.data!)
    );
  }
```

my get products resolver -

```
class ProductsResolver
  implements
    Resolve<
      Pick<IProductInterface, 'image' | 'title' | 'price' | 'description'>[]
    >
{
  constructor(private productService: ProductService) {}

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<Pick<
  IProductInterface, 'image' | 'title' | 'price' | 'description'>[]
  > {
    return this.productService.getProducts(
      route.paramMap.get('gender'), - error is here
      route.paramMap.get('category')
    );
  }
}
```

i get the error on -  `route.paramMap.get('gender')`
i would like to know how can i assing that to be the enum type.
thanks!

Answer (score 0):

2 problems:

- If you don't specify what your enum values equal to (i.e. `Men = 'Men'`), then they're assigned numbers. You could `parseInt` your parameter, but you should validate it to be a proper enum value anyway.
- Even if your enum values mapped to strings, you can't assign `string | null` to `string` since the value could be `null` and `null` cannot be assigned to `string`. And `route.paramMap.get('gender')` **can** return `null` if the parameter is missing. You should validate that anyway.

For the second problem, if you're 100% sure that the parameter will be present, use `route.paramMap.get('gender')!`. The `!` tells TypeScript "I'm sure this is not `null` or `undefined`".

Comment: when i pass it to the server, i get NaN.

Comment: You mean when you `parseInt` it? That means it's not a number. If you meant to use the enum name, you could use `ProductGender[gender]`, i.e. `ProductGender['Men']`, but mind that that's case sensitive.

Comment: the type remains a string, it does not solve my problem.

Comment: route.paramMap.get(ProductGender[gender])
you mean like that?